# How to get coin address balance from *coind server?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core-accounts, balance

Im running *coind on my local ubuntu box.

I see that "*coind getbalance [account]" will get me the total balance of a user account. And thats good and that works fine.

How do I get the balance of a individual users wallet (assuming they have more than 1 wallet associated with their account). For example, I have Wallet 1 with 10 coins and Wallet 2 with 20 coins for a total balance of 30 coins. How do I check the balance of the individual wallet (wallet 1 or wallet 2)?

I dont see any commands to view an individual addresses balance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also take a look at those:

- **getreceivedbyaddress** <*coinaddress> - it does display you how many *coins have been moved to this particular address. It doesn't subtract payouts, which should be handled internally.
- **getreceivedbyaccount**  - use this instead of above if you use accounts.

Additionally, you can provide a second parameter to those being a minimal number of confirmations.

Answer (score 1):

You can type '**bitcoind help**' to get the available commands. You can also type '**bitcoind help** *command*' to get more information about the command.

You can find your balance in multiple ways:

**getbalance**: returns the balance of your wallet.dat as a number, you can specify an account (if set) in quotes to get information for a specific account, the default account is '' (blank)

**getinfo**: returns an array of information about your bitcoind, including balance

**listunspent**: returns an array unspent outputs sent to addresses in your wallet.dat, you can put an address in quotes to get information for a specific address